# How to find out all the necessary IAM permission I need to run this function?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have 'written' a function for copying objects from one location on a S3 bucket to another within the same bucket. (Actually it is mostly code lifted off from [s3cmd](https://github.com/krux/s3cmd-pkg/blob/master/s3cmd)).

```
import sys
import time
from copy import copy
import logging
from S3.Exceptions import *
from S3.S3 import S3
from S3.Config import Config
from S3.FileDict import FileDict
from S3.S3Uri import S3Uri
from S3.Utils import *
from S3.FileLists import *
from S3.ExitCodes import EX_OK


LOG = logging.getLogger()


# Unfortunately the s3cmd implementation uses a global instance of config object
# everywhere
cfg = None


def init_s3_cfg(access_key, secret_key):
    global cfg
    cfg = Config(access_key=access_key, secret_key=secret_key)

def cmd_sync_remote2remote(str_from_path, str_destination_base):
    '''
    This function is adopted from s3cmd project https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd
     because boto does not support recursive copy out of the box
    :param str_from_path:
    :param str_destination_base:
    :return:
    '''
    s3 = S3(cfg)
    LOG.info(s3.config.bucket_location)

    # Normalise s3://uri (e.g. assert trailing slash)
    from_path = S3Uri(str_from_path).uri()
    destination_base = S3Uri(str_destination_base).uri()

    LOG.info("from %s to %s" % (from_path, destination_base))

    src_list, src_exclude_list = fetch_remote_list(s3, from_path,
                                    recursive=True, require_attribs=True)
    dst_list, dst_exclude_list = fetch_remote_list(s3, destination_base,
                                    recursive=True, require_attribs=True)

    src_count = len(src_list)
    dst_count = len(dst_list)

    LOG.info(u"Found %d source files, %d destination files" %
             (src_count, dst_count))

    src_list, dst_list, update_list, copy_pairs = compare_filelists(src_list,
                                dst_list, src_remote=True, dst_remote=True)

    src_count = len(src_list)
    update_count = len(update_list)
    dst_count = len(dst_list)

    LOG.info(u"Summary: %d source files to copy, %d files at destination to delete"
             % (src_count, dst_count))

    # Populate 'target_uri' only if we've got something to sync from src to dst
    for key in src_list:
        src_list[key]['target_uri'] = destination_base + key
    for key in update_list:
        update_list[key]['target_uri'] = destination_base + key

    def _upload(src_list, seq, src_count):
        file_list = src_list.keys()
        file_list.sort()
        for file in file_list:
            seq += 1
            item = src_list[file]
            src_uri = S3Uri(item['object_uri_str'])
            dst_uri = S3Uri(item['target_uri'])
            extra_headers = copy(cfg.extra_headers)
            try:
                _response = s3.object_copy(src_uri, dst_uri, extra_headers)
                LOG.info("File %(src)s copied to %(dst)s" % { "src" : src_uri, "dst" : dst_uri })
            except S3Error, e:
                LOG.error("File %(src)s could not be copied: %(e)s" % { "src" : src_uri, "e" : e })
        return seq

    # Perform the synchronization of files
    timestamp_start = time.time()
    seq = 0
    seq = _upload(src_list, seq, src_count + update_count)
    seq = _upload(update_list, seq, src_count + update_count)
    n_copied, bytes_saved, failed_copy_files = remote_copy(s3, copy_pairs, destination_base)

    # Process files not copied
    debug("Process files that was not remote copied")
    failed_copy_count = len (failed_copy_files)
    for key in failed_copy_files:
        failed_copy_files[key]['target_uri'] = destination_base + key
    seq = _upload(failed_copy_files, seq, src_count + update_count + failed_copy_count)

    total_elapsed = max(1.0, time.time() - timestamp_start)
    outstr = "Done. Copied %d files in %0.1f seconds, %0.2f files/s" % (seq, total_elapsed, seq/total_elapsed)
    LOG.info(outstr)

    return EX_OK

def remote_copy(s3, copy_pairs, destination_base):
    saved_bytes = 0
    failed_copy_list = FileDict()
    for (src_obj, dst1, dst2) in copy_pairs:
        LOG.debug(u"Remote Copying from %s to %s" % (dst1, dst2))
        dst1_uri = S3Uri(destination_base + dst1)
        dst2_uri = S3Uri(destination_base + dst2)
        extra_headers = copy(cfg.extra_headers)
        try:
            s3.object_copy(dst1_uri, dst2_uri, extra_headers)
            info = s3.object_info(dst2_uri)
            saved_bytes = saved_bytes + long(info['headers']['content-length'])
            LOG.info(u"remote copy: %s -> %s" % (dst1, dst2))
        except:
            LOG.warning(u'Unable to remote copy files %s -> %s' % (dst1_uri, dst2_uri))
            failed_copy_list[dst2] = src_obj
    return (len(copy_pairs), saved_bytes, failed_copy_list)
```

It works ok if the s3 keys have all the S3 permissions. However I want to use an IAM with a subset of permission to call this function. Here is my current group policy:

```
{ 
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "cloneFiles",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::target-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

With this new policy, I got this error messages:

```
ERROR:root:S3 error: Access Denied
```

I want to know:

1) Is there an easy way to work out what permission is missing (e.g. a certain parameter, env var)? Can S3 report which permission is required? If so, how can I find out?

2) Can anyone, by reading the code or otherwise, identify the missing permission?

Comment: Why are you taking code from s3cmd? You should use the [official AWS SDK for Python](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). You might also consider using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), which has excellent commands for Amazon S3, such as `aws s3 sync` that will synchronize files to/from S3.

Comment: I need to drive the process programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to #2, you're likely tripping up on the fetch_remote_list() call. That uses `s3:ListBucket`. Of note, ListBucket applies to the bucket resource, not Object paths in the bucket (a subtle but important distinction). So you'll want a second Statement like

```
        {
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket",
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::target-bucket"
        ]
    }
```